# python3 -- nested while loop driven user input menu decision tree

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, nested

I have been stumped on this one for too long and I need some help.  I am trying to create a user input menu decision tree that will lead the user to the appropriate function call.  I just cant seem to get the path to function correctly.  I keep getting stuck in the second loop.  I have tried many different logics and conditions but nothing has made it work.  I created some simple code that I think clearly shows what I am trying to achieve...

```
def menu():
    print("1. Selection 1")
    print("2. Selection 2")
    print("3. Quit")

def menu1():
    print("1.Selection Function 1")
    print("2.Selection Function 2")
    print("3.Quit")

def menu2():
    print("1.Selection Function 3")
    print("2.Selection Funtion 4")
    print("3.Quit")

def func_1():
    print("Funtion_1")

def func_2():
    print("Funtion_2")

def func_3():
    print("Funtion_3")

def func_4():
    print("Funtion_4")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   menu()

selection=int
selection1=int
selection2=int

while (selection != 3):
   selection==int(input("Please Select a Menu Option: ")) 
   if selection == 1:
       menu1()
       while ((selection1 != 3)):
           selection1==int(input("What Type of funtion Would You Like To execute: ")) 
           if selection1 == 1:
               func_1()
           if selection1 == 2:
               func_2()
           if selection1 == 3:
               sys.exit()
   elif selection == 2:
       menu2()
       while ((selection2==int(input("What Other Type of Function Would You Like To execute: ")) != 3)):
           if selection2 == 1:
               func_3()
           if selection2 == 2:
               func_4()
           if selection2 == 3:
               sys.exit()

   elif selection == 6:
       sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to break out of the while loop instead of doing `sys.exit()` in the inner loops. If you do `sys.exit()` on inner loops it will exit and won't come back to the outer menu option.

your this line `selection==int(input("Please Select a Menu Option: "))` should be `selection=int(input("Please Select a Menu Option: "))`. `==` is used for comparison not for assignment. for assignment we use `=`

Here, is modified code which works as expected.

```
def menu():
    print("1. Selection 1")
    print("2. Selection 2")
    print("3. Quit")

def menu1():
    print("1.Selection Function 1")
    print("2.Selection Function 2")
    print("3.Quit")

def menu2():
    print("1.Selection Function 3")
    print("2.Selection Funtion 4")
    print("3.Quit")

def func_1():
    print("Funtion_1")

def func_2():
    print("Funtion_2")

def func_3():
    print("Funtion_3")

def func_4():
    print("Funtion_4")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   menu()

selection=int
selection1=int
selection2=int

while (selection != 3):
   selection=int(input("Please Select a Menu Option: "))
   if selection == 1:
       menu1()
       while ((selection1 != 3)):
           selection1=int(input("What Type of funtion Would You Like To execute: "))
           if selection1 == 1:
               func_1()
           if selection1 == 2:
               func_2()
           if selection1 == 3:
               break
   elif selection == 2:
       menu2()
       while (selection2 != 3):
           selection2=int(input("What Other Type of Function Would You Like To execute: "))
           if selection2 == 1:
               func_3()
           if selection2 == 2:
               func_4()
           if selection2 == 3:
               break

   elif selection == 6:
       sys.exit()
```

Comment: I have added that in my code, you need to add break statement whenever you want to exit from inner menu selection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply viveksyngh!  hmm, when I change the "==" to "=" i get an invalid syntax error.  This why it is there originally.  However, when I cut and paste your code, it runs , but it again stalls at the second loop and does not execute the function.  DO you have any suggestions how I can get the path to execute func_1() for example?

Comment: Thanks again vivek! Okay, I think I get it now.  I need to insert a break statement after each function.  Let me give it a shot.

Comment: Can you give me an idea how to cancel the outer loop after the function is called?  Presently the function prints and then it goes back to the outer loop requesting another selection.  The outer while loop condition is != 3.  So I tried setting selection == 3 before the break command after the function but this did not work either...'if selection1 == 1:             
                func_1()
                selection == 3
                break'

Comment: Add a `break` inside outer inside each inner if block after function call and `selection=3`.

Comment: Like as below .   
           ```
           if selection1 == 1:
               func_1()
               selection=3
               break ```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `selection` with integer. Where selection has datatype, it will false forever. Instead do this `selection == type(3)` and this won't solve your problem.

One more thing is, first line in while loop

```
selection==int(input("Please Select a Menu Option: "))
```

here you are comparing(`==`), not assigning value(`=`).

```
selection=int(input("Please Select a Menu Option: "))
```

use single equals to symbol.

You can't compare the numbers, so you won't get required results, loops will be same for all numbers. For that you need to store numbers in selection variable. 
Ask for further queries.